# localhost/phpmyadmin 404 error

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have installed phpmyadmin, but doesn't seem to work.
I have apache2, php5, php-cgi, mysql-server, mysql-client installed too.
I've added the next line to the apache2.conf file:

```
#include phpmyadmin
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/*.conf
```

But when I restart the server, I have the next error:

```
* Restarting web server     apache2                                                                           [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/phpmyadmin/lighttpd.conf:
Invalid command 'alias.url', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

And the error log says:

```
[Tue Aug 13 12:36:25.690262 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13210] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.1-2+debphp.org~precise+2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 13 12:36:25.690358 2013] [core:notice] [pid 13210] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Aug 13 12:39:21.635566 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13210] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

What should I do to define alias.url, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: try changing `*.conf` to `apache.conf`

Comment: Yes. Now it's forbidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with @Jamie Taylor comment: *try changing *.conf to apache.conf*. 
Then get 403 response *forbidden*, and solved it by adding:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"> </Directory>
```

in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

And don't forget to uncomment:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.conf`, if you want to use PHPMyAdmin without password (only localhost, of course).